# [CCActionRepeatForever duration]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am attempting to move a CCSprite up and down on the screen using CCSequence and CCRepeatForever but I keep getting an error. The code for my method is below and the line of code that is throwing the exception is marked with a comment.

```
-(void) beginMovingAtSpeed: (float) speed
    {
        CGSize viewSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
        float yMin = viewSize.height * .14f;
        float yMax = viewSize.height * .86f;

        CGPoint start = self.position; // here you will get the current position of your sprite.
        CGPoint end = ccp(self.position.x,yMax);

        float distance = ccpDistance(start, end); // now you have the distance

        float duration = distance/speed;  // here you find the duration required to cover the distance at constant speed

        CCActionMoveTo* firstMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:CGPointMake(self.position.x, yMin)];
        CCActionMoveTo* secondMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:speed position:CGPointMake(self.position.x, yMax)];
        CCActionMoveTo* thirdMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:speed position:CGPointMake(self.position.x, yMin)];

        id repeatSequence = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCActionSequence actionOne:secondMove two:thirdMove]];

        // THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
        CCActionSequence* finalSequence = [CCActionSequence  actionOne:firstMove two:repeatSequence];

        [self runAction: finalSequence];
    }
```

Just in case anyone else encounters this problem, CCActionCallBlock was my solution and the following code is my workaround:

```
{
    CGSize viewSize;
    float yMin;
    float yMax;
}
    -(void) beginMovingAtSpeed: (float) speed
    {
        viewSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
        yMin = viewSize.height * .14f;
        yMax = viewSize.height * .86f;

        CGPoint start = self.position; // here you will get the current position of your sprite.
        CGPoint end = ccp(self.position.x,yMax);

        float distance = ccpDistance(start, end); // now you have the distance

        float duration = distance/speed;  // here you find the duration required to cover the distance at constant speed

        CCActionMoveTo* firstMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:CGPointMake(self.position.x, yMin)];

        CCActionSequence* sequence = [CCActionSequence actionOne:firstMove two:
                                      [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
                                       {
                                           [self performSelector:@selector(startAutomaticBarMovement:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:speed]];
                                   }]];

        [self runAction: sequence];
    }

-(void) startAutomaticBarMovement: (NSNumber*) duration
{
    CCActionMoveTo* secondMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:[duration floatValue] position:CGPointMake(self.position.x, yMax)];
    CCActionMoveTo* thirdMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:[duration floatValue] position:CGPointMake(self.position.x, yMin)];

    [self runAction: [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                      [CCActionSequence actionOne:secondMove two:thirdMove]]];
}
```

Comment: Show us the exception traceback and the method that the traceback indicates as causing the exception.

Comment: Here is a link to the traceback http://imgur.com/cVDaj1J I had to read a tutorial on tracebacks to get this...lol I hope this helps, thank you.

Comment: If you study the data you  provided you will see that `two` is a CCActionRepeatForever object, and that (the exception is trying to tell you) does not have a `duration` property.

Comment: Ok Great, you have been a big help. Learned some essential debugging techniques from this. I have edited my question and posted my workaround in it. Thanks a lot Hot Licks!

Comment: You're welcome! It's always more rewarding on both ends when the person asking the question is willing to learn, vs just wanting someone to give him an answer.